# Where does this NullPointerException come from?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, dijkstra

```
for(Node<T> neighbor : current.getAdjacentNodes()) {
    neighbor.setDistance(current.getDistance() + neighbor.getDistance());

    queue.add(neighbor);
}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException from this for-loop. I dont really know how to avoid this. 
I already tried to ask (if neighbor == null) { break } but this doesn work either.

This is my class. http://pastebin.com/hKMrG6h2

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at src.Node.getDistance(Node.java:69)
at src.Dijkstra.populateDijkstraFrom(Dijkstra.java:35)
at DijkstraTest.TestCase1(DijkstraTest.java:34)
```

Dijkstra.java:35 is my for-loop

[ORIGINIAL CODE] http://pastebin.com/k7Mu18YE
[CLASS CODE] http://pastebin.com/hKMrG6h2

Comment: Is `current` maybe null? Post your exception and on which row it occurs.

Comment: i´ve tried some checks and i think my problem is   neighbor.getDistance()  but i am not sure how to check if the neigbor is "the last one"

Comment: Can't you post stacktrace?

Comment: Is `queue` initialized? Can you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: @kukis update in my main post

Comment: You haven't posted the relevant code. Your stacktrace clearly shows the the NullPointerException occurs *inside* the method `Node.getDistance`.

Comment: Print the line 69 of Node.java

Comment: @ErwinBoldwidt okay. i posted my nearly full code now.

Comment: That's not the code that threw that exception.  Dijkstra.java line 35 doesn't contain a call.  Node.java line 69 cannot involve nulls.

Comment: First figure out where the exception was actually thrown.  You've got 3 lines listed there, any of which could be throwing the exception.

Comment: Note that the exception is occurring inside `getDistance`.  You haven't even shown us that code.

Comment: @HotLicks its in the [CLASS CODE]...

Comment: What @kukis said.  (Auto-boxing/unboxing is evil.)

Answer (score 1):

The distance field has Integer type. But the getter for that field returns primitive int. When you call getter and the field is not initializated or has null value it will throw NPE. Thats because JRE tries to [Unbox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) Integer type to primitive int. And you can't assign null to int.

I attach short code that reproduce that behavior.

```
    public class Testy {

    static Integer v;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getDistance();
    }

    private static int getDistance()
    {
        return v;
    }
}
```